# Sort a chunked array and make sense of it

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm using this code:

```
$chunked = array_chunk($items,3,false);
```

which outputs something like this:

```
array(11) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "Volvo"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "1000"
    [2]=>
    string(7) "50000"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "Saab"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "1200"
    [2]=>
    string(7) "40000"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Lexus"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "900"
    [2]=>
    string(7) "55000"
  }
}
```

What I want to do is to sort this chunked array properly based on these criterias.

1. Extract the 2 cars with the highest cost (third datapoint)
2. Out of these 2 cars check which one has traveled the most miles (2nd datapoint)

So output would be:

1. Volvo - 50000 - 1000
2. Lexus 55000 - 900

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I am pretty new to using arrays this way.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically looking for a `usort` function. As per [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

> usort — Sort an array by values using a user-defined comparison function

First, I'd sort the whole array by the third key (assuming `$z` is your array). Then unset the last element and resort the array by the second key:

```
usort($z, function($a, $b) {
    return $b[2] - $a[2];
});

unset($z[2]);

usort($z, function($a, $b) {
    return $b[1] - $a[1];
});
```

The value in the end should be the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Volvo
            [1] => 1000
            [2] => 50000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Lexus
            [1] => 900
            [2] => 55000
        )

)
```